Bash script with "openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -config server_openssl.cnf --passin pass:password"
I am writing a bash script that will generate a root certificate and a server certificate. The root certificate generation works, but the server certificate prompts me for input - however since this is a bash script it should just use the values from the config.
rootCA_openssl.cnf
[ req ]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
 
[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName = NO
countryName_default = NO
stateOrProvinceName = Nordland
stateOrProvinceName_default = Nordland
organizationName = Lumina Ventures
organizationName_default = Lumina Ventures
commonName = Lumina Ventures Root CA 1
commonName_default = Lumina Ventures CA 1
 
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:true
keyUsage = critical, keyCertSign

Genrsa
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out rootCA.key --passout pass:password 2048

Create a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) file for root CA certificate
openssl req -new -key rootCA.key -out rootCA.csr -config rootCA_openssl.cnf --passin pass:password

Generate root CA certificate file rootCA.pem
openssl x509 -req -in rootCA.csr -sha512 -signkey rootCA.key -out rootCA.pem -days 1095 -extensions v3_req -extfile rootCA_openssl.cnf --passin pass:password

server_openssl.cnf
[ req ]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName = NO
countryName_default = NO
stateOrProvinceName = Nordland
stateOrProvinceName_default = Nordland
localityName = Lofoten
localityName_default = Lofoten
organizationName = Lumina Ventures
organizationName_default = Lumina Ventures
commonName = 80.50.50.20
commonName_default = 80.50.50.20
commonName_max = 64
 
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
 
[ alt_names ]
IP.1 = 80.50.50.20

Enter a passphrase when prompted
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out server.key --passout pass:password 2048

req (it stops here)
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -config server_openssl.cnf --passin pass:password

This prompts me with:
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
NO [NO]:

How can I use the default values in server config? I tried to add prompt = no to the [ req ] section but it gave me a new error:
Error making certificate request
4057E170FB7C0000:error:04000067:object identifier routines:OBJ_txt2obj:unknown object name:../crypto/objects/obj_dat.c:376:
4057E170FB7C0000:error:05800077:x509 certificate routines:X509_NAME_ENTRY_create_by_txt:invalid field name:../crypto/x509/x509name.c:252:name=countryName_default

The last thing I am going to do is to generate the certificate, however I am stuck at the openssl req
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -sha256 -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -out server.pem -days 1095 -extensions v3_req -extfile server_openssl.cnf


See also https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/3536

There is no sense in adding _default values when prompt = no is used as you are setting the values in the config file. These defaults are only used if the user doesn't enter anything at the prompt.
Use something like:
[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName = NO
stateOrProvinceName = Nordland
localityName = Lofoten
organizationName = Lumina Ventures
commonName = Lumina Ventures Issuing CA 1


It worked when I removed the default values. I also had to remove "commonName_max = 64". Will that make problems with the certificate?

Not at all.  That setting is the maximum number of characters which the operator can enter as the common name.  As you're now not entering that value (it's in the config instead) then the option is also irrelevant.
